# How to unset -fstack-protector flag with g++?

Tags: c++, g++

When I launch g++, I see a lot of default flags : `-mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection`.

Anyone knows how to unset `-fstack-protector-strong` ?

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You undo that option with

```
-fno-stack-protector
```

or

```
-fstack-protector
```

if you only want the basic protection.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

UPDATE:

The option `-fno-stack-protector` is really not documented explicitly. It is part of the generic options handling of gcc. As the [general options documentation says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC):

> Many options have long names starting with `-f' or with` -W'—for example, -fforce-mem, -fstrength-reduce, -Wformat and so on. Most of these have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of -ffoo would be -fno-foo. This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default.

Comment: Thx! But it's really strange that `-fno-stack-protector` isn't documented !

Comment: It is a general pattern of negating options. "Many options have long names starting with `-f' or with `-W'—for example, -fforce-mem, -fstrength-reduce, -Wformat and so on. Most of these have both positive and negative forms; the negative form of -ffoo would be -fno-foo. This manual documents only one of these two forms, whichever one is not the default. "  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC